Resolving 'Not Found' Error in VS Code with Ballerina Project Setup
I’m new to Ballerina and I am running into an issue in Visual Studio Code.
I'm seeing a "Not Found" error at the bottom of the editor while trying to set up my Ballerina project.
I've already installed the Ballerina SDK, configured the path in VS Code settings, and checked that the extension is updated.
I have set environment variables properly, and in the VSCode I have put the ballerina home path properly.
Here’s a screenshot of what I’m seeing. Any advice on what might be causing this?


You don't need to configure the Ballerina home path in VS Code settings or as an environment variable.
The Ballerina installer will automatically set up all the required symlinks/environment variables during installation, and the Ballerina VS Code extension will auto-detect the system’s Ballerina version based on these settings.
Therefore you can revert any custom configurations you’ve added and follow the exact steps in the Ballerina VS Code Extension Get Started Guide. Also, ensure that you’re using the correct Ballerina installer to install Ballerina on your system.

I have done , but still I have that error

Note: ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang issue 13448 (from 2019) reports a similar bal: command not found error message, but just got closed as completed (Nov. 2024), with:

PR 5730: "Rename bal.windows.gitbash to bal in windows distribution"
PR 43481:  "Add "proxy script" to be able to run bal in Windows Git Bash"

This should be released soon, and will be able to check if your issue persists.
